# NASM: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand

Tags: assembly, linker, nasm, operands

Sorry if this is very much a newbie question, I have been trying to make a simple assembly program that compares two numbers. However, when I attempt to compile the program using NASM, I get this error:

```
increment.asm:21: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
increment.asm:21: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
increment.asm:22: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
increment.asm:22: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
increment.asm:23: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
increment.asm:23: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
increment.asm:24: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
increment.asm:24: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
increment.asm:31: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
increment.asm:31: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
increment.asm:35: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
increment.asm:35: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operan
```

I have absolutely no idea what's going on!
Here is my code (Compiled using NASM and ld):

```
  1 %macro writesys 2
  2         mov eax, 4
  3         mov ebx, 1
  4         mov ecx %1
  5         mov edx %2
  6         int 0x80
  7 %endmacro
  8 
  9 %macro readsys 2
 10         mov eax, 3
 11         mov ebx, 0
 12         mov ecx %1
 13         mov edx %2
 14         int 0x80
 15 %endmacro
 16 
 17 section .text
 18         global _start
 19 
 20 _start:
 21         writesys enternum, 17
 22         readsys num1, 5
 23         writesys enternum, 17
 24         readsys num2, 5
 25 
 26         cmp num1, num2
 27         je equal
 28         jne notequal
 29 
 30 equal:
 31         writesys equalnum, 26
 32         jmp exit
 33 
 34 notequal:
 35         writesys notequalnum, 29
 36         jmp exit
 37 
 38 exit:
 39         mov eax, 1
 40         int 0x80
 41 
 42 section .data
 43         enternum db "Enter a number: "
 44         equalnum db "The two numbers are equal"
 45         notequalnum db "The two numbers arent equal"
 46 
 47 section .bss
 48         num1 resb 1
 49         num2 resb 2
 50
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: In your macros you have a number of lines missing a comma. For example `mov ecx %1` should be `mov ecx, %1`

Comment: @MichaelPetch Works, totally overlooked that. Thank you.